# Legality of reading others direct messages

Tags: internet

Are there any legal ramifications to an employee reading the direct messages of another employee, whether the reading employee is logging in with another users credentials or not (reading over the shoulder, etc), especially then acting on the information included in those messages?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if these messages were delivered using the employer's channel (employer email etc.) or are stored on the employer's computer they are the employer's messages not the employee's. Unless the employee is exceeding their explicit or implicit conditions of employment by reading/acting on these messages there are no legal issues. If they are, then the employer can take disciplinary action.

If they are private messages on a private computer: don't show them to other people.